# Sunspot cannot index has_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sunspot

I want to index has_many association on a Model like this, but when I search by tag name it cannot find the record:

```
searchable do
  text :name, :author, :toon_type
  text :tags_names do
    tags.map(&:name)
  end
  time :created_at
end
```

Any idea? My tags are polymorphic association through a tagging model is that a problem?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

I am manually index through the console by object.index, in my log:

SOLR Request (5.3ms)  [ path=# parameters={data: Toon 86ToonActiveRecord::BaseToon2013-08-22T22:46:09Zpapabearanimation, headers: {"Content-Type"=>"text/xml"}, method: post, params: {:wt=>:ruby}, query: wt=ruby, path: update, uri: xxx:8982/solr/update?wt=ruby, open_timeout: , read_timeout: , retry_503: , retry_after_limit: } ]

Search method

```
@search = Sunspot.search(Toon) do
  fulltext params[:search]
  order_by :created_at, :asc
  # with(:created_at).less_than Time.now
  # with(:created_at).greater_than(1.week.ago)
  paginate :page => params[:page], :per_page => 9
end
@toons = @search.results
```

Search request:

Processing by SearchController#result as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "ga_client_id"=>"", "search"=>"testerabc"}
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 5 LIMIT 1
  SOLR Request (43.9ms)  [ path=# parameters={data: fq=type%3AToon&sort=created_at_d+asc&q=testerabc&fl=%2A+score&qf=name_text+author_text+toon_type_text+tags_text&defType=dismax&start=0&rows=9, method: post, params: {:wt=>:ruby}, query: wt=ruby, headers: {"Content-Type"=>"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"}, path: select, uri: localhost:8982/solr/select?wt=ruby, open_timeout: , read_timeout: , retry_503: , retry_after_limit: } ]

Comment: Can you include the code you are using to search?  Also, it would be helpful if you included the logging information from Sunspot (should be in the Rails log).

Comment: That log message is from the indexing.  Do you have the log message from the search Solr request?